# What is the difference of "createBitmap" and "createScaledBitmap" ,when get a fixed height and width photo

Tags: android, bitmap

I want to import a photo,then show it in ImageView that its "Height" and "Width" is fixed.First,I input the pohot by `BitmapFactory`and `options.inSampleSize` to get the bitmap.Second,I want to get the photo ,but I dont know which I can use in `createScaledBitmap(Bitmap src, int dstWidth, int dstHeight)` and `createBitmap(Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height)`.

I have see `Android Developer` docs ,but I still fuzzy.I think that `createScaledBitmap` have change the size of the photo,but the `createBitmap` can cut the photo whatever I want.

```
 public static Bitmap getBitmap(String filePath, String fileName, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {


    if (filePath.length() <= 0 || filePath == null) {
        return null;
    }
    String fullPath = filePath+"/"+fileName;
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fullPath, options);
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    Bitmap photoBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fullPath, options);

    return photoBitmap;
}


public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;
        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}
```